# Using a Case statement to set a parameter based on another parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to set an SQL variable based on the numerical value of a different SQL parameter passed into a stored procedure, but having trouble with the exact syntax of the Case statement

```
DECLARE @RangeText varchar(1)

SELECT CASE  
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 1) 
THEN SET @RangeText = '=' END
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 2) 
THEN SET @RangeText = '>' END
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 3)  
THEN SET @RangeText = '<' END
ELSE NULL
END
```

I'm sure it will be something small like a missing keyword or something, but when I search Google all I seems to be able to find is setting a the same variable, not a second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Correct syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @RangeText varchar(1)

SELECT @RangeText = CASE  
                      WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 1) THEN '=' 
                      WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 2) THEN '>' 
                      WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 3) THEN '<'
                      ELSE NULL
                    END
```

or:

```
SELECT @RangeText = CASE  @SecondsOnSiteRange 
                       WHEN 1 THEN '=' 
                       WHEN 2 THEN '>' 
                       WHEN 3 THEN '<' 
                       ELSE NULL
                    END
```

Answer (score -2):

You should only use end at the end like this:

```
SELECT CASE  
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 1) 
THEN SET @RangeText = '=' ELSE
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 2) 
THEN SET @RangeText = '>' ELSE
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 3)  
THEN SET @RangeText = '<' ELSE
ELSE NULL
END
```

I am extremely sorry the above is incorrect. I did overlook, below is how it should be done...

```
SELECT @RangeText = 
CASE  WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 1) 
THEN '=' 
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 2) 
THEN '>' 
WHEN (@SecondsOnSiteRange = 3)  
THEN '<' 
ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is not used to control flow. Your code is not going to work because it has syntax errors.

Comment: When I added this in I got all the same syntax errors as before

Comment: Sorry everyone. In being quick I have overlooked and did make all the necessary changes.